# Is BOOT_COMPLETED required for WorkManager?

Tags: android-workmanager, firebase-job-dispatcher, android-job

Is `RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED` permission required for WorkManager to reschedule the workers after reboot? if not how WorkManager handle this?

Comment: Asked google: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/129362589

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Yes, it is.  The WorkManager manifest already contains this permission
>   and it should get manifest merged into your app automatically in most
>   cases.

from Google WorkManager team.